# jqueryui sortable: video stops when drop element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using the jquery sortable: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

I have a problem for html5 video: when I drag and move : video still plays fine. 
But when I drop a video element, it stops to play.

Any idea ? (or alterntaive to sort html5 videos elements ?)

My code:

```
$('#VideosContainer').sortable({cancel:'.videoClass'});
$('#VideosContainer').disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome, this appears to be related to the [following bug:](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=382879).

I was able to work around the issue by simply calling the `play()` method on the video element that was moved. The sortable's `stop` callback worked best for me, as this is fired every time an element is dropped, regardless if it was actually sorted or not, and contains the dragged element in `ui.item`.

For example:

```
$('#foo').sortable({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    var video = ui.item.find('video').get(0);
    video.play();
  }
});
```